# Excel Deleting duplicate entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to delete duplicate entries in the following table:

[image: original]

The problem is that I only want to delete the duplicates in the left hand column, and the right hand column entries must stay with their corresponding row, so that the table becomes:

[image]

When I follow the advice given [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx), I get this:

[image]

Which is still not right as there are still duplicates in the left hand column. The problem is that it sees the rows as unique, although I am actually only interested in the left hand column.

Any advice?

Comment: There are no duplicates, the match on the left does not match on the right. If you want the cells in column 2 to stay with column 1, it needs to keep at least one column 1 for each column 2. If, say, you want it to only keep the highest of the values in column 2 for each column 1, you will need to tell it to do that.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I am indeed interested in the higher numbers. How would I go about 'telling it'? (-: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can add a column to your sheet, you can add a formula next to those and drag it down

```
 =IF(AND(A2=A1,B2<=B1),"Remove","Keep")
```

Then sort on that new column to only show "Keep". Or, only show "Remove" and then delete those rows and unfilter the data. This will work with duplicates, but not necessarily with triples, etc.

Otherwise, a VBA solution may be required.